# Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing with google play services

Tags: android, admob

I looked at all the others questions but I don't found my answere
i got this code

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
   android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
       ds:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,C8D15E364178"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

But it says " Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing"
I tried also creating the banner from the activity but nothing changed

Comment: What says? Your IDE (which is?) or at runtime (show the log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use the new Google Play Admob. Then check also [this guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

With this version of Admob you must set Test devices & load ads **programatically** instead of doing this in xml. Note that in Google Play Admob `ads:testDevices` and `ads:loadAdOnCreate` attributes are **no longer available** ==> Remove those attributes from the xml!

See this example of how you can do it in the Activity:

```
// Java code required.
// testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
// no longer available.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Please check my update and get rid of the no longer available attributes to get your xml properly parsed

Comment: Did you _completely_ remove the `loadAdOnCreate` and `testDevices` attributes?

Comment: Yes, and i also tried to change to com.google.ads.adView

Comment: Try clean project? Which admob library do you actually use?

Comment: The last one, i just downloaded it.

Comment: Ok, then you cannot add loadAdOnCreate and testDevices attributes. Try adding this to your AdView: `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: I've done all from the start and now it works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
To make your ad working with Google Play Services

Here is the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"/>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is your java file

```
package com.google.example.gms.ads.xml;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} which embeds an AdView in its layout XML.
 */
public class BannerXMLSample extends Activity {

  private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID_HERE";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}
```

Refer the example here
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner-xml

Comment: Also of note for those switching FROM adMob's older method, make sure to replace your xmlns:ads property in the LinearLayout (or whatever you are using) with this: `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 2):

My requirement was to be able to dynamically pass in ad unit IDs instead of specifying them in xml. Turns out the framework does not like a mix of these, so I am creating my ads 100% programmatically:

```
public class AdMobBanner extends FrameLayout {

private AdView adView;

public AdMobBanner(Context context, AdParams params) {
    super(context);

    adView = new AdView(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(params.getAdUnitId());
    addView(adView);
}

public void showAdvert(AdParams params) {
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();

    for (String id: params.getTestDevices()) {
        builder.addTestDevice(id);
    }
    adView.loadAd(builder.build());
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    adView.pause();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    adView.resume();
}

}
```

The AdParams class is my own class and you can replace it with your own class, or pass in strings, but the general solution is posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This page should explain some of the confussion with Admob SDK and Google Play Services.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/play-migration

Your XML is good.
Except you can't use the following with Google Play Service:

```
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/
ads:testDevices="
```

With Google Play Services you can not use device id in xml for your banner like we used to with Admob Sdk. With Google Play Services, you can only place device ID in the java code.

..............
Creating AdView in XML and loading an ad

```
//CODE XML FOR Admob BANNER:

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


// No Java code required.

//...............................................................
//CODE XML For Google Play Banner:

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>


// Java code required.
// testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
// no longer available.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....
    ....
    ....
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```